# Make Azure AD Login Page The Default Sitecore Login Page

Tags: login, azure-ad

I'm using sitecore 9.3.

Is there a way to redirect to AD login page instead of the sitecore identity server default login page?

This Page:

[image]

instead of the below page:

[image: Sitecore Default Login Page]

Comment: Did you check `Forcing a Login` section in this blog 
https://www.symsoftsolutions.com/blog/2020/01/02/sitecore-9-azure-active-directory/ ?

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal I dont want to create another site, I only want to change the default login page to redirect to Azure AD login page. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to set **loginPage** attribute of **shell** site to **$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd**.

This will redirect **/Sitecore/Login** or **/Sitecore** to AzureAd login page directly

Here is patch config-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration  xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="shell" set:loginPage="$(loginPath)shell/SitecoreIdentityServer/IdS4-AzureAd" />      
    </sites>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This is also documented [HERE](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/use-the-sitecore-identity-server-as-a-federation-gateway.html)